# Python semaphore "hangs" in tight loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been having an issue with Python Semaphores appearing to "lock" for an unbounded amount of time when there is a tight relationship between acquire/release. I do not have this issue with Lock/RLock

Below is code distilled to to the simplest case which exhibits the concerning behavior.

```
import threading
import time

sem = threading.Semaphore()
#sem = threading.RLock()

exit = False

def spinner():
    while(not exit):
        sem.acquire()
        time.sleep(1)
        sem.release()

t = threading.Thread(target=spinner)
t.start()

print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.gmtime())
for i in range(0,10):
    sem.acquire()
    print "Accessed!"
    sem.release()
print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.gmtime())

exit = True
t.join()
```

When I use the semaphore method, this takes an unpredictable amount of time (sometimes 20 minutes!)

When I use a Lock or RLock, this completes quickly as I expect.

Am I missing something? It seems like semaphore with the default value=1 should behave the same as Lock.

According to the documentation I'm looking at, calling release on one thread should unblock an indeterminate other blocked thread. However what I think is happening is that the thread which calls the release is free to keep running, then re-acquire if it is still within its time-slice. When hitting acquire again it sees an unblocked semaphore and gets access again. Bad luck thus forces the waiting thread to keep waiting a long time.

Am I missing something? Why would Lock/RLock work any better?

Comment: That's interesting! I tried it with both python 2 and python 3. It worked as you described with python 2. On python 3, Lock and RLock had the same problem as the Semaphore with python 2.

Comment: This may be a partial answer to my own question (doesn't explain the Lock/RLock behavior), but this may be a manifestation of the GIL, and a fundamental [python flaw](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf). It seems like the logic still works even if using threading vs. processes.